# ASP.NET: How to Create an Expandable Empty TreeNode

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

I need to populate the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` on the event of `TreeView.TreeNodeExpanded`. The problem is the node is empty before the event gets fired and it is not expandable in this case and there is no expand icon **[+]** showed next to it.

I want to make the node expandable in case its related object has some children without adding those children to the node.

I thought about adding a virtual child to the node and delete it when it is expanded. Are there any better options ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three steps to do the trick:

1 - Set the [TreeView.ExpandDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth.aspx) to *0*. This eliminates the expansion of the added `TreeNode` objects in the `TreeView` and shows the expansion symbol **[+]** next to each `TreeNode` that has the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

2- Set the [TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.populateondemand.aspx) to *True* for each *branch* `TreeNode`. When the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` collection is *empty*, the expansion symbol **[+]** will be showed only next to `TreeNode` objects that has `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to *true*.

3- Handle the [TreeView.TreeNodePopulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx) event to poulate branch nodes on expansion. This event will be fired when a `TreeNode` - with the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` set to *true* - has been expanded right before the `TreeView.TreeNodeExpanded` event gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest editing the template of the node. Have a look at [An ASP.NET AJAX TreeView control with templates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/OdcTreeView.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure and do not have time to try but I guess what you are after is the [TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.populateondemand.aspx) property and [TreeView.TreeNodePopulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx) event.

Comment: I know that part.. I need to make the `TreeNode` expandable before populating its items if it has some.