# ASP.NET: Get TreeNode's Container TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

How to get the container `TreeView` of a `TreeNode` ??

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way other than *reflection*:

```
TreeNode node = GetNode();
TreeView view = 
    (TreeView) node.GetType().
        GetProperty("Owner", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).
            GetValue(node, null);
```

Comment: That's right for `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode` but not for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode` ...

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. Have you checked my other question [ASP.NET: How to Create an Expandable Empty TreeNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661192/asp-net-how-to-create-an-expandable-empty-treenode) ??